# LCDS Vs BlazeDs

Tags: flex3, blazeds

Hi Any one can explain the difference between the LCDS and BlazeDs. Both are supporting HTTPService,Webservice,Remoting service. So why we need BlazeDs or LCDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I can think of off the top of my head for **needing LCDS *over* BlazeDS**:

1. You want proper paid support, and not the serve-yourself approach to support of the open source community.
2. You need to scale your messaging, especially push messages, to a very high number of concurrent users.  BlazeDS apparently does not compare well to LCDS in that regard.

That said, **BlazeDS has two key advantages over LCDS**, at least from my direct experiences:

1. It is 100% Java, so can run just about anywhere.  (LCDS has native code.)
2. It is free!

Comment: Sorry for the archeology; one more point about needing LCDS over BlazeDS, it's when your application deal with data management services (DataService, flex.data.ChangeObject for example), two parts that are not included in BlazeDS replacement.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of features that are included only in LCDS. Two main ones for me would be PDF generation and Data Management. Both boost the speed an application can be developed. If I remember correctly there is a free single-CPU licence of LCDS which gives you Data Management but still watermarks PDF-s.

To see how Adobe compares them: [link](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/compare.html)

Answer (score 0):

BlazeDS is free and open source... LCDS is pretty expensive. LCDS also provides a lot of other Live Cycle features that are not included in BlazeDS (Like a better push architecture, can handle more clients, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe comparison page mentions that only LCDS has lazy loading - that sounds rather relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a articles which explains clearly the differnces between LCDS and Blazeds

http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/blazeds-and-lcds-feature-difference/

I used LCDS because it supports PDF generation.